# Should I go about creating a class that can be used to store information parsed from JSON text using QT C++?

Tags: c++, json, qt, class, parsing

**Question summary**

Should I go about creating a class that can be used to store information parsed from JSON text using QT C++? What would be a better alternative?

***NOTE!!!!***

I can only post 2 links because I'm a newb but if you would like to have more information to answer the question here is all of my research. Go down to question and you'll be able to see all the useful links I have about my research.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/17pHPPtHZOUpFgmzubnGLTAzqmtHaycazTjm0D7qLl40/pub

**More details about the question**

I am facing a number of difficulties, here they are listed below.

1. I’m okay creating a class that will accept Bool, Null, Double or String. However I don’t understand how to accommodate for arrays and objects in JSON.
2. I am pretty stumped when it comes to finding what data type an array is. I can’t seem to get it?
3. I need to create another function that would go through an array or object in JSON and parse the values in an object. Not sure how. If you want to go the extra mile and understand how to parse an array in an object that would be lovely as I have no idea how I would approach that.
4. How should I setup my class to handle data that are objects.

Let me know if any of my assumptions, coding practices and methodology is wrong. I would love to receive some constructive feedback.

**Overall aim of my program**
To communicate with a TinyG module and convert the information received from JSON to meaningful information. The overall project is to make a UI to control a robot, hence why QT is being used.

**Assumptions**

1. You can assume that another module has converted serial communications from the TinyG to a QString. Hence don’t worry about the TinyG I thought I would give you some extra information about my project.
2. The JSON string input will follow the most current version of the TinyG which can be here ().

**Notes**

1. I am using QString over a regular string because it is easier to use.
2. I like to comment the hell out of everything because these are my learning notes.
3. To find documentation about TinyG and it’s JSON output please visit this link. DELETED/LINK
4. To find a detailed document with all of my research notes go via this link. 
   They’re messy and full of typos so don’t hate!
5. The main page about the TinyG can be found here. DELETED/LINK
6. I am using QT Creator Community 4.3.1
7. QT Json documentation can be found here. DELETED/LINK I’ve also had a look at the save game example.
8. I’ve posted this on other sites to get a fresh perspective :)

Other components of the question
.zip file

**Source code**

***jsontodata.h***

```
#ifndef JSONTODATA_H // An if statement for header files. If JSONTODATA_H is not defined then execute everything from here to #endif

#define JSONTODATA_H


// Include libraries that are essential to jsonToData

#include <QString> // Allows the use of QStrings

#include <QStringList> // Allows for QStringList which is essential to iterator over the variable's name.

#include <iostream> // Allow for cerr. The c standard error stream

#include <QJsonDocument> // Allow for QJsonDocument. Which responsible for converting QString to JSON

#include <QJsonObject> // Allow for QJsonObject. Responsible for converting QJson into a format that can be iterated through with keys

#include <QJsonValue> // Allow for QJsonValue. Essential for knowing data types of variables stored in JSON

#include <stdbool.h> // To allow for bool variable types

int jsonToData(QString Input); // Function prototype


#endif // JSONTODATA_H
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <jsontodata.h> // Allow the use of jsonToData function

#include <string> // allows for string data type


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    QString data = "{\"variables\":43.5}";

    std::cout << data.toLocal8Bit().constData() << std::endl;

    jsonToData(data);

    QString data1 = "{\"variable_name\":null}";

    std::cout << data1.toLocal8Bit().constData() << std::endl;

    jsonToData(data1);

    QString data2 = "{\"xfr\":null,\"variables\":43.5}"; // Must have , not },{

    std::cout << data2.toLocal8Bit().constData() << std::endl;

    jsonToData(data2);

    QString data3 = "{\"r\":{\"xjm\":5000000000.000},\"f\":[1,0,11,6649]}";

    std::cout << data3.toLocal8Bit().constData() << std::endl;

    jsonToData(data3);

    QString data4 = "{\"sr\":{\"line\":1245,\"posx\":23.4352,\"posy\":-9.4386,\"posz\":0.125,\"vel\":600,\"unit\":\"1\",\"stat\":\"5\"}}";

    std::cout << data4.toLocal8Bit().constData() << std::endl;;

    jsonToData(data4);

}
```

**jsontodata.cpp**

```
#include <jsontodata.h>


// ----------------- temp class declaration ----------------------------------------------, move to header file when done.
// Constants for data type
#define TYPE_ARRAY 4
#define TYPE_BOOL 1
#define TYPE_DOUBLE 2
#define TYPE_NULL 0
#define TYPE_OBJECT 5
#define TYPE_STRING 3
#define TYPE_UNDEFINIED 128 //Usually an error, out of bounds array or non existent key in an object

/*
// Description:
class JsonValue
{
    int DataType; // According to defined constants
    QString VariableName;
    QJsonValue Data;
    JsonValue Previous;
    JsonValue Next;
};

class DataFromJson
{
  int numValues;

};



// ----------------- temp class declaration ----------------------------------------------
*/


// Author: A.S.
// Date: 26/07/2017
// Summary: Converts a string (a QString specifically) to meaningful data. Does so by converting into an object and getting the key list then iterating through and returning the variable's data type, name and data.
// Note 1: JSON has a key (variable name) and value (the variable's data).
// Note 2: QStringList has variable names sorted alphabetically.
// Note 3: If QJsonObject.value(QString) does not exist then the QJsonValue returned will be undefined.
// Note 4: TinyG has a number of cases where is shortcuts the JSON string, to avoid this TinyG must be in strict mode.
// Note 5: Can't have a duplicate key. Hence strings will have to be sent line by line to TinyG.
// return(0): JSON was interpreted correctly
// return(-1): Unknown error, there was a scenario that was not considered.
// return(1): Document is empty. Not neccisarily an error however.
// return(-2): JSON string could not be passed. Hence something is wrong with the given text
// return(-3): Document does not contain an object. Most likely an error in the JSON string
// return(-4): JSON object could not be produced. Most likely an error in the JSON string
int jsonToData(QString Input)
{
    int Ret = -1; // Define the return variable.
    QJsonValue temp; // temporary QJsonValue used to
    QStringList::const_iterator VariableIterator; // Used for looping through different variable names in JSON text
    // Convert JSON into an object that can parse JSON in a string format
    QJsonDocument Doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(Input.toUtf8());

    // Check that there were no errors, if there were then it will return a null document
    if(Doc.isNull() == false)
    { // Correctly passed JSON string

        // Determine if the document is empty, if so report it
        if(Doc.isEmpty() == false)
        { // Document is not empty

            // Determine if the document contains an object
            if(Doc.isObject() == true)
            { // Document contains object

                // Convert document to an object, if there is an error the object will be returned as empty
                QJsonObject Obj = Doc.object();

                // Check conversion
                if(Obj.isEmpty() == false)
                { // Document was converted correctly to an object

                    // ------------------------------------------------- Make into Function the can recursively call itself -----------------------
                    // Find the key (or variable) names
                    QStringList VariableList = Obj.keys();

                    // Loop through and determine variables, values and datatypes
                    for(VariableIterator = VariableList.constBegin(); VariableIterator != VariableList.constEnd(); ++VariableIterator)
                    {
                        std::cout << "Name: " << VariableIterator->toLocal8Bit().constData() << std::endl;

                        // Remove grab value based on key.
                        temp = Obj.value(*VariableIterator); // If the key does not exist then temp will be null, picked up by isUndefined()

                        std::cout << "Type: ";
                        switch(temp.type())
                        {
                        case TYPE_ARRAY:
                            std::cout << "Array" << std::endl;
                            // Assign to JsonValue but not sure how to figure out whichdata type it is.
                            break;
                        case TYPE_BOOL:
                            std::cout << "Boolean" << std::endl;
                            std::cout << "Data: " << temp.toBool() << std::endl;
                            //JsonValue.Data = temp;
                            // Get data some how to object
                            break;
                        case TYPE_DOUBLE:
                            std::cout << "Double" << std::endl;
                            std::cout << "Data: " << temp.toDouble() << std::endl;
                            //JsonValue.Data = temp;
                            // Get data some how to object
                            break;
                        case TYPE_NULL:
                            std::cout << "Null" << std::endl;
                            //JsonValue.Data = temp;
                            // Get data some how to object
                            break;
                        case TYPE_OBJECT:
                            std::cout << "Object" << std::endl;
                            // Holllllly fek not sure how to go about looping through because you could have an array in an object in an object. However it will follow TinyG output.
                            // How the hell to assign this to an object??
                            // This does my head in :'( halp
                            break;
                        case TYPE_STRING:
                            std::cout << "String" << std::endl;
                            //JsonValue.Data = temp;
                            //Get data some how to object
                            break;
                        case TYPE_UNDEFINIED:
                            std::cout << "Undefined" << std::endl;
                            // Report error, don't assign data
                            break;
                        default:
                            std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // ------------------------------------------------- Make into Function the can recursively call itself -----------------------

                }
                else
                { // Error converting document to object
                    std::cerr << "Document could not produce an object" << std::endl;
                    Ret = -4;
                }
            }
            else
            { // Document does not contain object
                std::cerr << "JSON does not contain an object" << std::endl;
                Ret = -3;
            }
        }
        else
        { // Document is empty
            std::cerr << "Docuemnt is empty" << std::endl;
            Ret = 1;
        }
    }
    else
    { // Error parsing JSON string
        std::cerr << "Error[-2]: Could not parse JSON string. Document is null." << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Doc.isObject() = " << Doc.isObject() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Doc.isArray() = " << Doc.isArray() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Doc.isEmpty() = " << Doc.isEmpty() << std::endl;
        Ret = -2;

    }
    return Ret;
}
```

Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCAO0.png)

Comment: Read about the classes: QJsonObject, qjsonarray, qjsonvalue

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, it has already been created long ago

Comment: Please read the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, Your question is broad, and that's off topic in SO.

Comment: Hi Eyllanesc, thanks for the really quick response. I feel like the way I've gone about solving this problem is going around in circles. It was a bit broad, I'll remember to hone in on specific problems for next time. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Please delete this question.

Comment: Your problem, if I understand it correctly, is solved by `QJson*` classes. As soon as your data is read by `QJsonDocument` you don't need to store it anywhere else (unless it's really needed). The only thing you have to learn is how to traverse `QJsonObjects` and extract data out of them.

Answer (score -1):

That really depends on the specific JSON you're parsing:

1. Usually arrays are represented as std::vector, or QList (or other container type the you would deem appropriate, given the problem you're trying to solve.)
2. any container type from STL or QT
3. Usually the contents of an array can be defined as a separate class. It all depends on the JSON and your specific problem. If the array contains the same data as your class, and your class can contain other objects of your class then you would use recursion.
4. It seems like you are going backwards here. JSON is a way of representing your class, so it can be saved/sent across the internet. If you have that in mind then there's a 1-to-1 relationship between your class members and the JSON.

Comment: Hi Eyal, thanks so much for the almost instantaneous reply! I was tossing up whether or not to create a class which information could be stored in at all. I haven't decided exactly how i'm going to interpret responses from the TinyG hence why i've made this module. Thanks for clarifying that this really was a silly idea going about the problem this way! :)